# Good Computer Package for Calculating Inverse of a Formal Power Series?

Tags: computer-algebra, mathematical-software

This might be a question people already asked or is obvious to experts, or is not appropriate for this forum, if so, I apologize. I am trying to calculate things like $z/(e^z-1)$, or find the inverse of $x=z+ 2z+5z^2+\cdots$, expand as power series. What is the best (or favorite) software package you use to do stuff like this?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseSeries.html

Comment: Sage can do it: http://www.sagemath.org. (Search hint: finding the inverse function of a power series is called "Lagrange inversion", or sometimes "reversion".)

Comment: Probably every symbolic algebra package that handles power series can do it.  Maple has several ways, such as the function *reversion* in the powseries package and the *solve/series* function.

Comment: Pari/GP's serreverse().

Comment: In flint library (flintlib.org) there's a bunch of functions for computing inverse series in different fields. For example, fmpz_poly_inv_series

Comment: Assuming you mean the compositional inverse, fmpz_poly_revert_series. flint is a good choice if you want say 10000 terms.

Comment: You don't say what kind of answer you're looking for. Would you be happy with a list of numerical values for a finite part of the list of coefficients or are you looking for something in a symbolic form where possible?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I've gathered the answers from the comments in alphabetical order.

1. [flint](http://flintlib.org/) has the fmpz_poly_revert_series command (A web search revealed a reference pdf, but no web page).  Some benchmarks seem to indicate that flint is unusually fast.
2. [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/) has the [reversion](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=powseries/reversion) command.
3. [Mathematica](http://wolfram.com/) has the [InverseSeries](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseSeries.html) command.
4. [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) has the serreverse function.
5. [SAGE](http://sagemath.org/) has the [reversion](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/power_series/sage/rings/power_series_poly.html#sage.rings.power_series_poly.PowerSeries_poly.reversion) command.

Answer (score 0):

For the TI-nspire CAS calculator: http://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/424/42499.html.

Answer (score 0):

Maple produces it. See http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=powseries , especially the command http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=powseries%2freversion for info.